# Draw something over omxplayer

Tags: kodi, omxplayer, pygame

I am playing a video with OMXPlayer in fullscreen mode.

What I want to do is to draw something. I want to see my video by transparency.

I have tried with pygame, but I cannot see both videos and drawings...

Any idea to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For OMXPlayer's side of things, you can use the `--layer` option to set where OMX player draws the video in relation to other objects.  As long as the drawing utility you use supports transparency and the same function when rendering, it's then just a matter of specifying the order (e.g., use `--layer 2` on OMXPlayer, and the equivalent for layer 3 on the drawing utility).